# Clarification on a limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I am looking for a formal proof that
If $$\lim_{x\to a} h(x)=\pm\infty$$ then $$\lim_{x\to a}{\huge(}1+\frac{\alpha}{h(x)}{\huge)}^{h(x)}=e^\alpha$$
I understand that h(x) tends to infinity but I don't know how I can formally prove this. I know the heine and cuschy definitions of limits.

Comment: 1. What is your definition of $e$? 2. Are you okay with using L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: How can a limit approach postive $∞$ and negative $∞$ at the same time? Can you please explain me? I learnt limits just a few months ago

Comment: @Gwen It can't approach both of those at the same time. What your statement is saying is that it's true in both cases. That is, whether $h(x)$ approaches $+\infty$ or $h(x)$ approaches $-\infty$, the same conclusion follows.

Comment: @user469053 the limit definition and no.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)= \bigg(1+\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)^{h(x)}$$
Then
$$ \ln f(x) = h(x) \ln \bigg(1+\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)$$
Or
$$\lim_{x\to a} \ln f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} \bigg[h(x)\ln \bigg(1+\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)\bigg]$$
Or
$$\lim_{x\to a} \ln f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} \bigg[α\frac{\ln \bigg(1+\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)}{\bigg(\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)}\bigg]$$

As $x\to a$ so $ h(x) \to \infty $ hence $\frac{α}{h(x)}\to 0$. We also know
$$\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+k)}{k} = 1$$

Hence $$\lim_{x\to a} \ln f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} α × \lim_{x\to a}\bigg[\frac{\ln \bigg(1+\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)}{\bigg(\frac{α}{h(x)}\bigg)}\bigg]$$
Or
$$\lim_{x\to a} \ln f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} α $$
Or
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} e^α = e^α $$

Comment: Thanks! Very clear proof

Comment: Can you approve my answer please. It will help others as well. Also +1 to the question, and thanks for appreciating my process :)

Comment: Can you also explain why $\lim_{k\to 0} \frac{\ln(k+1)}{k}$ and if using substitution explain why can you use the substitutition